# How to remove "Developer" tab from Settings in iphone ios 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have this new tab of "Developer" -> Power ->Logging , added to my Settings in iphone 3GS with ios  4.2.1 , when I connected it to Xcode and then clicked on "Use it for Development".
I know that it is used for getting power consumptions by various apps through Xcode instruments.
Is there a way to remove this tab from settings permanently ? I dont want it.

Comment: Come on... It's just a tab :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to restore your iPhone or maybe there is way to hide this tab when your iPhone is jailbreaked, but come on this little tab is not very annoying ;)

Comment: Thanks! but r u sure after restoring it, the tab will be removed?bcoz if i restore it ,my phone would be locked again.

Comment: If you restore the iPhone in iTunes the tab would be away, because you don't use it for development anymore. When you use it then with Xcode the "developer" tab will appear.

Answer (score 1):

After removing your developer profile in Settings --> general --> profile, 
reboot your iPad/iphone (push power button 5 sec.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to restore your phone.